# Centering a child inside it's parent

Tags: html, css

I'm working to center #child within #parent at 100% height and width. Why does setting the #child top position to 10% work, but using 10% as a margin-top does not?

http://jsfiddle.net/rbtstudio/SCmfG/

```
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #parent {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #323232;
    }
    #child {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        background-color: #eaeaea;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 10%;
    }
    /*
    #child {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    */
</style>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works on chrome for me.

Comment: I'm asking why it works using positioning and not margin. 10% of the height is 10% of the height... but margins don't seem to calculate it right.

Comment: `margin-top:10%` also works for me: it just also pushes the parent down as well.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/SCmfG/2/ for one way with margin.  Or also http://jsfiddle.net/SCmfG/3/.

Comment: @Mash why does margin-top work against html instead of against parent (or even body) since child is contained in parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is called "collapsing margins".  You can read more about them in the css spec.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

It's not that the margin isn't working, it's that the margin is collapsing, causing the margin to apply to the top of the parent box.

You'll notice that when the margin is applied to the child, the parent is moved down.

http://jsfiddle.net/SCmfG/4

One workaround (of many) to avoid the collapsing of margins is to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element:

http://jsfiddle.net/SCmfG/5/

**EDIT:** Another important point to keep in mind (which was in another answer which has since been deleted) is that all percentage margins are based on a percentage of the width of the element, even top and bottom.

Comment: jsfiddle of the margin code:  http://jsfiddle.net/SCmfG/4/  Also, the spec may be a bit hard to read.  If you google for collapsing margins there should be tons of people who explained it in simpler terms.